# How to find by a relative path in jcrQuery (Sql2)

Tags: sql, magnolia, jcr-sql2

I´m trying to find a node by a relative path:

I need to search a node which terminates in : 3265

I´m using queries like that:

```
SELECT * from [mgnl:news] AS t WHERE ISSAMENODE([/%/3265])
```

I need to know how to find a node by a relative path, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That´s the answer:

```
Select * from [mgnl:news] as t where name(t) = '3265'
```

This returns my node: /Application/news/3265

Thanks also.

Comment: Well, it may because you are typically query by name instead of path :) Happy that you found your way, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like

```
Select * from [nt:base] where path like '%.%'
```

For more examples please have a look at 
[https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/JCR+Query+Cheat+Sheet](http://Magnolia%20Jcr%20Query%20Cheat%20Sheet)

Cheers,

Comment: this not function, also i´m trying like that: Select * from [mgnl:news] where [jcr:path] like '%201003181%'" and not function

Comment: Are you using JCR Queries app ? May i learn where do you execute this query from ?